# How to set image content for a button for windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to set image for a button,my images doesn't contain text in it, i want to set text for that image manually, i tried this way button with a button content of image,but i dono how to set text for it, i am working in Visual studio 2012 for windows mobile 7

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonName" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
          <Image Source=image.JPG" Stretch="Fill" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
          <TextBlock Text="picture Button" TextAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Thing is donot set the content property of the button.
Also give appropriate size to the button otherwise image control will make it excessively big

Put your controls inside the stackpanel which can take many children instead of only one child as supported by button, and you can control the size more easily.

---

Based on the image you gave, here is my code. Also you should put that image link in your question

```
<Button  Content="Text" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="0">
     <Button.Background>
          <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
               <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                   <GradientStopCollection>
                       <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FF03CCF0" />
                       <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF0182C2" />
                   </GradientStopCollection>
               </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
           </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Button.Background>
  </Button>
```

Change button size according to requirement. Also you may need to change the background for other visual states using VisualStateManager, but the result will be much cleaner. Also there is very dirty trick too. I am not posting code for it.
use a canvas as content, set it's background and then insert a textblock inside. I don't know will this work, but I wont do it anyway. using VisualStateManager is recommended.

Comment: then how about checking it as answer. It will fetch me points and will be useful to others in future as well.

Comment: sry it doesn't working, i can't set image content, by using above code i can do button with more no. of controls,but i need to set content or text for  that image, i am having image with empty content how can i achieve this?

Comment: No pressure to check it as answer. I posted the solution after trying it out in device. So it is working. Maybe if you can explain clearly what you want or edit the question.

Comment: What i need to do is. i am having .png image with 370X150 height and width, i added this image in button with a grid of fixed size, now i want to add content for this empty image.how it is possible?content with hello or something, can i get any sample code to achieve this task?

Comment: can you provide a rough screenshot of what you want. I still doesn't get it. You have a .png file which you are using as content. Then how is that an empty image.

Comment: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/231/imageple.png/) here i send the screenshot of my image, just i want to add "Hello" in that image using C#, how it is possible?

Comment: Edit the question as per your requirements to others will stumble upon your similar question and mark anyone as answer if your problem is solved. Cause that's not how SO works. If someone sees your question is very different to your requirement you may get down voted in future for this question.

Comment: I need to add Text or Content for an .png image using C#. Master Chief 2nd  sample code works fine for me.Though, i cant set content for image i can achieve this task by providing background for button and content for text..

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way for an Image to act as a Button is to set the style property.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value >
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="Images/Sample.jpg" />
            </ControlTemplate >
        </Setter.Value >
    </Setter >
```

Set this code in your page by defining a new block `<Grid.Resources></Grid.Resources>` or you could do it universally in the `StandardStyles.xaml` and when you're defining a new Button set the `BasedOn` property to the Key value that you've defined in the style.